# How do I move Sticky Notes content to another computer

Tags: windows-7, sticky-notes

Sticky Notes in Windows 7 - where are the files actually stored, ie, how can I move the content to another computer?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

All notes are stored in one file:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt
```

or possibly

```
%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt
```

Note that this isn't a text file, and it contains both current notes and vestiges of old notes; i.e. it's not exactly useful for sharing stuff.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me, I simply copied the file from the location on the source computer into the same location on the destination computer (overwriting the old file)

Comment: I used this technique to copy from my old Windows 7 computer to my new Windows 8 computer and it worked, so I guess the format is compatible/unchanged. Cool.

Comment: I think you missed out the Roaming %AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt. Anyway that's not difficult to find where only got 3 folders in %AppData% :)

Comment: There is some confusion here. `%AppData%` is actually a shortcut to `AppData\Roaming` and is not the same as the `AppData` folder. Opening cmd and running `cd %AppData%` changes the directory to `AppData\Roaming`.

Answer (score 3):

> AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\stickynotes.snt

At least in Win 7, you must run Sticky Notes first to create the directory and file. Note that `AppData` is a hidden directory.

Copy and paste the file, and the next time you run Sticky Notes your old notes will appear.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7, notes are stored in `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\` folder in `StickyNotes.snt` file. This file can be copied to a different profile in the same machine or to different  machines.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 7 either 32 or 64 bit OS it is stored in the following path (replace `username` with actual username)

```
c:\users\***username***\appdata\roaming\microsoft\sticky notes\stickynotes.snt
```

Copy the file and paste in to the other user's profile.