# How to sync notes created from Sticky Notes so as to reuse them among different PCs?

Tags: windows-7, sync, sticky-notes

I use multiple PCs and need my notes sync between them. I prefer to use Sticky Notes in Windows 7 other than any other 3rd-party tools. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution for you is as below.

You need:

1. Symbolic link (recommend [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html))
2. [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/referrals/NTYxOTQ5MDQ5)
3. The location of the "data" of the notes
   i.e. in %AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt (referenced from [source](https://superuser.com/questions/101463/how-do-i-move-sticky-notes-content-to-another-computer))

How to sync the notes:

1. Go to the notes data file and create a symbolic link
2. Save the symbolic link in your dropbox folder
3. Done.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I just make the "Sticky notes" folders sharable & use SyncToy to sync them.

Answer (score 1):

I know that you said that you enjoy the Sticky Notes app that is bundled with Win7 however, what about a nifty product like simplenoteapp.com?  It has a Linux, [Windows](http://www.resoph.com/ResophNotes/Welcome.html), Mac OS X, and mobile versions so you can take your notes on the road.  Notes, at least for me need to be accessible everywhere, fast, and sync seamlessly.  Just an idea going forward.

Comment: Hi, I've tried going to simplenoteapp.com and try to download a version for Windows. But it's confusing, they introduce two other tools from other companies. What do you say about that? http://simplenoteapp.com/downloads/

Comment: I have played with the [resophNotes](http://www.resoph.com/ResophNotes/Welcome.html) program and it seems to be a very competent and free app.  I deviated towards it mainly because of its light resource load.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another, more elegant method, which doesn't involve using the command prompt and it is less error prone. It involves using the [Steam Mover](http://www.traynier.com/software/steammover) application. Complete step by step instructions are found here: [How to Sync Sticky Notes Across Users and Computers in 7 Steps](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-sync-sticky-notes-across-users-and-computers-7-steps).

Answer (score 0):

This approach: http://www.guidingtech.com/14871/sync-sticky-notes-dropbox-skydrive-google-drive/ requires no 3rd-party apps (other than Dropbox, skydrive, or similar)