# Lost content of Sticky Notes application on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sticky-notes

I lost some important information on my sticky notes by deleting the text inside and saving it. Is there anyway to recover the sqlite file with the original content?

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/101463/how-do-i-move-sticky-notes-content-to-another-computer?rq=1 before you point out that the question is about Windows 7, I am aware of that fact, but the information is 100% applicable to Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 store the sticky notes under %LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftStickyNotes_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState

File is plum.sqlite. You can manually backup at next time

But it updated when you edit on the stickies. So, seems we cannot restore once you removed on stickies.

Answer (score -1):

- Take a look inside the file, maybe the fragment's still there. Apparently the file's
  `%AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt`
  or
  `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt`
- There might be a program that could search all of ram, in case the fragment's still in ram somewhere, but opening a web browser & finding & installing it could overwrite your ram. Your posting this question may have done that already.
- Or search the swap file. The same ram overwriting issues apply.
- Or search the hard drive's free space in case it moved the file when it saved it. If it hasn't been overwritten. A hex editor or grep would do it, if you can open your drive's partition like a file (i.e. Linux).
- Check your clipboard? If you "cut" or copied the data maybe it's still there, or using a clipboard manager would save the last few entries (but that's a security risk, saving in ram only's not as bad as a file).

---

In the future, make a backup of important info.